# Winforms\WPF - How to create flow chart alike graphic

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, graphics, charts

I'm writing a winforms application and I need to create a view simliar to this one:
[image: flow chart]

Any suggestion how to do it? perhaps it would be easier using WPF?

I thought about drawing rectangles or some sort of a table. Is there any open source control that can do it more easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a load of aptions:

- [GraphSharp](http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/) (free)
- [WPF Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) (free)
- [FlowChart.NET](http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html) (commercial)